# buying crypto kittie TxReceipt Status: Fail

Tags: myetherwallet, etherscan, cryptokitties

I'm confused about the following. I'm trying to buy a crypto kittie which price is 0.0038 ETH. On myetherwaller the following window is shown.
[image]
"Amount send in most cases you should leave this to 0"
Isn't the reason why the transaction fails is because im not sending the 0.0038 ETH to pay for the kittie? When I click on generate transaction im transfer to Metamask 
[image]

But as shown in the image above in the amount is set to 0, shouldn't it be the price of the crypto kittie? Ain't this the reason why the transaction gives a status of fail?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x912e248489d056b427d39f69b3d5d3221b262624dc6b0c0f0faa4936dd82f24b

If in myetherwallet the amount send should be set to zero shouldn't I be able to update the amount send in metamask? What to I need to do to buy the crypto kittie?

Comment: set the amount to send as the price of the kitty.

Comment: that didn't work either @user83948 https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ffead50e4166f7893b945efb323a3dfc31b632e5a4c25c27058be50a588b97a

Answer (score 0):

I've never bought crypto kitties but indeed i believe the amount to send should be the price of the kitty, in this case 0.0038 ETH so this is probably why it is failing.

Additionally, your gas limit seems a bit low, according to this [article](https://cryptokitties411.com/2018/01/05/gas-limit-and-gas-price/), a good value for crypto kitties is `250 000`.

Comment: but how do I add the 0.0038 on metamask if im only given the choices to update the Gas Limit and Gas Price? On myetherwallet the amount to send should be 0 and when I'm transfer to metamask I can only update the Gas Limit and Gas Price

Comment: I just tried sending the 0.0038 and raised the Gas Limit to 250 000 and still have a fial transaction status. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ffead50e4166f7893b945efb323a3dfc31b632e5a4c25c27058be50a588b97a

Comment: @jimmythechamp if you want to use metamask the transaction is already set up for you. You need to set how much gas you want to use for the transaction. I've used as little as 5 gwei for a purchase kitty transaction. ethgasstation.info has good information if you want to save yourself some gas.

Comment: @user83948  nothing seems to work! I just tried with 90000 Gas Limit and 4 gwei Gas Price. Still the transaction gave a status of fail. You can see it here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9e56e5e3f7d44cb59ac7f060bbf6d3126e91e2de66a37b19b43ac195723721f7

Comment: @jimmythechamp check this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-buy-a-cryptokitty-the-complete-guide-dna-sequencing-26e14596a9cf) in case you haven't already you might have missed something. Either way i just checked the official site and it seems they have some performance trouble so it might be a problem on their end, my advice would be to try again later.